# How to handle transactions in neo4jphp?

Tags: php, transactions, neo4j, neo4jphp

For relational databases like mysql, transaction handling in PHP is just like.

```
Begin transaction
...
Insert queries
...
Update queries
...
if error in any query then
Rollback transaction
...
at end, if no error in any query then
Commit transaction
```

How to handle transactions in [neo4jphp](/questions/tagged/neo4jphp)?

I have tried same like but there was failure. Even after rollback changes were saved.

I was doing like this.

```
//$client = Neo4jClient
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();
...
//Insert queries
...
//Update queries
...
//if error in any query then
$transaction->rollback();
...
// at end, if no error in any query then
$transaction->commit();
```

Comment: What errors did you see? Were they database errors or application errors? Also, if there is an error from the database, changes are automatically rolled back. You only have to call rollback explicitly if your application needs to cancel the changes.

Comment: @JoshAdell: Firstly I was not adding Query statements to transaction. Doing similar to mysql transactions. After resolving that I was getting errors like "Transaction is already closed". Because I was calling "$transaction->rollback();" again. Now I have resolved my problem. Thanks for your good plugin `neo4jphp` and thanks for your responce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following code.

```
//$client = Neo4jClient
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();

$dataCypherQuery = new Query($client, $dataQuery, $params);
```

Instead of getting resultset from query, we need to add statement into transaction.

```
// $dataResult = $dataCypherQuery->getResultSet(); // don't do this for transaction
```

Important : Pass query object to transaction's add statements method.

```
$dataResult = $transaction->addStatements($dataCypherQuery);
```

We can pass true as parameter indicating transaction commit.

```
//$dataResult = $transaction->addStatements($dataCypherQuery, true);
```

If there is an error, changes are automatically rolled back.
You can check $dataResult variable for validity, result should be returning something.

```
if (0 == $dataResult->count()) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

At end, if no error in any query then

```
$transaction->commit();
```

For more info see [Cypher-Transactions](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-Transactions)